# Inserting data into a table from another table in a specific way. Details and sample data shown

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have two tables: newTable and oldTable with columns Item Name and Item Quantity

oldTable:

- Item Name
- Item Quantity

newTable:

- Item Name
- Item Quantity

I need the data to look like this:

oldTable:

```
  Item Name| Item Quantity
 --------------------------
  ball     | 4
 --------------------------
  badItem  | 3
 --------------------------
  bat      | 2
 --------------------------
  badItem2 | 7
 --------------------------
  badItem3 | 2
```

newTable:

```
  Item Name| Item Quantity
 --------------------------
  ball     | 16
 --------------------------
  bat      | 2
```

I need to put items from the oldTable into the newTable BUT I can't insert into newTable where item name = badItem, however I do have to insert every listing of the badItem's quantity from the oldTable into the newTable and add it to the quantity of the first item listed in the newTable. NOTE: Baditem will have numbers after it, I just need to grab every item with the letters 'badItem' in it. User will know why an item of the newTable has such high quantity, knows beforehand that quantity of all the baditem(s) got added onto the one item of the newTable). I understand doing this doesn't make much sense as to why do this but it's required of me to do.

Any help on how to structure this SQL query is appreciated!

Comment: Rather hard to follow the garbled description - did oldItems become baditems somehow, somewhere?  Inserts dont have a WHERE condition, so in part you are probably needing an Update

Comment: (1) There is no "first item" in a table.  Tables represent *unordered* sets.  (2) You need to tag with the database you are using.  (3) Perhaps you should do this with a query rather than actually modifying the tables.

Comment: I would do two query, one that update newTable with the "badItem" and the other that insert the missing data.

Comment: How do you recognize the _good_ item that receives the increase in quantity from the _bad_ item? Without some kind of logic on this point you have no clue how to execute the update.

Comment: don't need to recognize the good item quantity from the baditem quantity in the newTable, it just needs to just go together for this newTable. I don't like it either but it's what I'm required to do. But no worries there are ways to separate it out if I need to but I'm just focusing on how to do what I said in my question.

Comment: @plutonix old items did not become bad items. newitems has all the old items except for the olditems named badItem but the baditem's quantity is needed in the newTable

Comment: @flutter go look at my editted question now, I think it's 100% clear what I need

Comment: Are you SURE that you have at most one value 'baditem' (in potentially multiple rows)? Or can there be several bad items (a_bad_item, b_bad_item, c_bad_item etc)? How does a row qualify as being a bad item row? Is a column missing here?

Comment: @flutter, weird I actually cleared that up right before you posted this comment. look at my question again. there are baditem, baditem2, baditem3 that all get put together and added to one item in the newTable

Comment: @flutter I think I came up with the solution... I put it down as an answer

Comment: @plutonix can you review my answer and see if that would work?

Comment: @the_lotus after you look at my edited question and look at my answer is that how you would do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do it in 2 steps:

1. Fist insert the valid items on newTable
2. Update the First item sum with total of bad items

   INSERT newTable ([Item Name] , [Item Quantity])
   SELECT [Item Name] , [Item Quantity]  FROM oldTable WHERE [Item Name] Not like '%item%' -- you need adjust to fit with your pattern

   UPDATE NT SET [Item Quantity] = NT.[Item Quantity] + (SELECT Sum([Item Quantity]) FROM oldTable WHERE [Item Name] like '%item%' )-- you need adjust to fit with your pattern 
   FROM newTable NT WHERE NT.[Item Name] = (SELECT TOP 1  [Item Name] FROM newTable)

Comment: I accepted this as an answer because it does answer my question but do you mind correcting your syntax on your UPDATE? thanks.

Comment: Thaks. I adjusted the syntax it.